# use Application variable in asp to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic

i am converting a old application from asp classic to ASP.net VB.  i find a code part in classic version where application variable is declared and i want to use this in my ASP.NET in Globel.asax file. I am getting confuse how i use this in my ASP.NET in globel.asax

**ASP Classic Code**

```
 if application("noticeupdate")="OPEN" or application("noticeupdate")="CLOSED" then
else
   application("noticeupdate")="OPEN"
end if
```

**ASP.NET**

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the application is started
    'Dim 
    If Application("noticeupdate") = "OPEN" Or Application("noticeupdate") = "CLOSED" Then

    Else
        Application("noticeupdate") = "OPEN"

    End If

End Sub
```

Can you help me how can i convert this function . 
Thanks for your reply

Comment: Isn't it the same? Or have you tried it and get an error?

Comment: @richaux i changed the code that i write in ASP.NET but i am still confuse about that how this in Classic version developer use

Comment: Some more information may help us: in what context is your Classic version called - is that from `Application_OnStart`? Also, does the new version not compile, or not get called, or cause an error?

Comment: does this produce an error? what you provided is incomplete.

Comment: @vhinnterrible only three line of code in classic asp globel page i also thinking how this line of code are working in classic ASP.Net Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax for same thing, I am not really understanding your code however...

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires when the application is started
    if application("noticeupdate")="OPEN" or application("noticeupdate")="CLOSED" then
        ...
    else
        application("noticeupdate")="OPEN"
    end if
End Sub
```

You can read more here regarding application state:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594(v=vs.100).aspx

And on the page you can do something like this to display the value:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Label1.Text = application("noticeupdate")
    'or Response.Write application("noticeupdate")
End Sub
```

Comment: how to use application() that use in ASP Classic Code

Comment: how can i acess this value on my page

Comment: @Abhishek if you mean on classic ASP page you can't, they do not share the Application context.